# Let f and g be two differentiable functions such that f'(x) <= g'(x) for all x < 1 and f'(x)>= g'(x) for all x > 1. Then relation bet f(1) and g(1)

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f$ and $g$ be two differentiable functions such that $f'(x) \leq g'(x)$ for all $x < 1$ and $f'(x)\geq g'(x)$ for all $x > 1$. Then relation between $f(1)$ and $g(1)$.
The four options are:
(A) if $f(1)\geq g(1)$, then $f(x)\geq g(x)$ for all$ x$
(B) if $f(1)\leq g(1)$, then $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x$
(C) $f(1)\leq g(1) $
(D) $f(1)\geq g(1)$ .

My approach:
Let $f(x) = \log_{10}x$ and $g(x)=\ln x$. But these two functions only satisfy for $x>0$ (Not for all $x$).
Here I am getting stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $h(x) = f(x)-g(x)$ has global minimum at $x=1$. If this minimum is nonnegative then $h(x)$ is nonnegative for all $x$. So (A).

Comment: Thank you kmitov. My only concern is by this logic option D could also be the answer?? Thanks again...:)

Comment: No. We cannot say anything about the value of $h(x)$ at $x=1$. So the answer is just (A).